# Does proving a statement for matrices prove it for linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we are required to give a proof for any linear transformation, can we use the fact that any linear transformation can be represented as a matrix, prove the equivalent statement for matrices, and conclude that the statement must be satisfied for the corresponding linear transformations?

For example, if we wanted to prove that a self adjoint linear transformation $f: V \rightarrow V $ has a cube root, it would be easier to use the Spectral Theorem on the corresponding matrices, $A$ then make an argument on the linear transformations.

Are there any technical obstacles preventing this?

Comment: generally fine in finite dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Some linear transformations act on infinite-dimensional spaces like the set of all functions from the reals to the reals; for those, a matrix representation may not be possible.

Comment: Though, it may be (for some, but not all properties) that "This holds for the transformation" is equivalent to "This holds for the restriction of the transformation to any finite dimensional space".

Comment: @ John - is it always not possible to find the matrix representation of linear transformations over spaces of infinite dimension, or must each be reviewed ad hoc?

Comment: It depends on what you call a "matrix". There are a couple of answers. My favorite is that a matrix is a *function* $m$ from $\{1, \ldots, k\} \times \{1, ldots, n\}$ to $\mathbb R$; the value $m(i, j)$ is typically written $m_{ij}$. With that def;n, there's a natural generalization to countably infinite matrices, where the domain is $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. But the proofs about such things tend to be tougher than the proofs about finite matrices. And this only works for countably-infinite-dim'l spaces. In the example I gave above, the domain is uncountably-infinite-dimensional.